# How to print out long text to multi-page

Tags: sql-server

A SQL `varchar(7900)` data need to be print out. It cannot fill in one page.
How to break it down to two pages without break a word.

I cannot use `substring(FieldA, 1, 3000)` and next page `substring(FieldA, 3001, 6000)`, because work for example "BOOK" may break to "B" as last letter in 3000 position, and "OOK" shows in the next page.

Comment: Does the data have new line characters?

Comment: You can start your length at 3000 and decrease it until you see a non-letter, then do the substring(FieldA, 1, length).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
SUBSTRING(FieldA, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FieldA, 2995))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @L INT;
DECLARE @str varchar(8000);
SELECT @str=FieldA FROM your_table WHERE ....
SET @L = 1;
IF LEN(@STR)>3000 SET @L=3000;
WHILE @L>2000 AND SUBSTRING (@str, @l, 1) LIKE '[A-Z]'
     SET @L=@L-1;
IF @L>1 BEGIN
    PRINT SUBSTRING(@str, 1, @L);
    PRINT SUBSTRING(@str, @L, LEN(@str)-@L);
END
ELSE
    PRINT @str;
```